# How to save a modified AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm using a community AMI, it's great but some of the stuff in it is outdated. Every time I spin up a new machine based on it I have to update all the libraries. I want to instead update them once and save the modified image. It's and EBS backed AMI. I tried creating a snapshot off of the volume of the running instance and then creating an AMI from the snapshot. The resulting AMI does indeed have all the modifications I made but the operating system is different! The original AMI has ubuntu while the thing that comes out is "other linux" - and some things are not working (CUDA). Both "RAM disk ID" and "kernel ID" in the original AMI details are blank so I leave them as "default" when creating the new AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to save a modified EC2 instance is to burn an AMI directly from the running instance, rather than taking a snapshot of its root volume.

If for any reason all you had was a snapshot of the root volume of a previously running instance, to create a bootable AMI you have to follow the following process: launch one of the stock EC2 AMIs, one that has the same OS as your EBS snapshot. Create an EBS volume from that snapshot. Stop the newly launched instance. Detach the root volume, and attach the new volume you created form the EBS snapshot as the root volume and start the instance. See [Launching a Linux Instance from a Backup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html).  NOTE: Although you can create a Windows AMI from a snapshot, you cannott successfully launch an instance from the AMI.

The easiest way to save an AMI with new modificationa, is to create the AMI image directly from the running instance, and not simply take a snapshot of the running volume.

From the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home), click on the instance, then right-click Image -> Create Image.

From that dialog, set the Name, Description etc. Make sure to leave No Reboot unchecked. From the Instance Volumes section adjust the volume settings.

Note that your instance will reboot during the image creation process. Make sure you are prepared for the temporary loss of service of the instance during this time.

Comment: I'm now creating the image from a running instance and same thing happens - it gets created as "other linux".

Comment: Have you tried to launch it and confirm?  I have never heard of a burned AMI image being burned with the wrong/different OS.  That would be a very grave problem for AWS.

Comment: My bad - it's the same ubuntu, it just appears under a different name in the console for no good reason. And the not working CUDA was broken by something else. Thx for the advice!